# Not able to load html files in my spring application

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to load my Spring application and I have only html files to render but it is not able show any html file. It is always showing 404 error. But when I am trying to run it directly html file using tomcat then it will able to show my html files.

Below is my directory structure

[image]

[image]

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ankServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>ankServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

servlet-context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
    <context:annotation-config />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .htmlresources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/resources/html/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".html" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="com.ankit" />

</beans:beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String displayLogin(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    {   
                return "login"; 
    }
```

Comment: which url do you request? (to the the login page for example)

Comment: Yes to the login page

Comment: @user1111880 write the url here like http://localhost

Comment: http://localhost:8080/SpringMVC/login

Comment: @user1111880 I used to suffer from 404 not found messages and found that Tomcat and Spring work better when static content is placed within the WEB-INF folder. Perhaps try creating a /static folder inside /WEB-INF and then moving the /html and /css folders (and contents) into the /WEB-INF folder and then adding <mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" /> within your servlet-context.xml. would also then need to change  <beans:property name="prefix" value="/resources/html/" /> to <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/html/" />

Comment: Ok i tried doing your way but unable to get any successful response.I think view resolver doesn't support .html rendering

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
 <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ankServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

To:

```
   <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ankServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: what is the use of putting <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>?